# Torrent Client - Command line - Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, software-rec, bittorrent

I just wonder Is there any command line torrent client ? 
Like `wget` downloader.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most of the common command-line clients should compile under [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) in Windows. I have [rtorrent](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/) running this way on a couple of Windows machines.

Edit: another thought: I assume that Python based clients should run under Windows too if you install Python. Though off the top of my head I can't think of such a client that is actively maintained (the original "official" client was Python based, but IIRC uTurrent has replaced that).

Comment: +1 Cool, rtorrent is awesome never thought of cygwin!

Comment: Guys. Why does cygwin compile, configure SOOOOO slow I get tired of my life ? Is there a way to speed it up? Shouldn't be it faster..somewhat?

Comment: configure/autoconf/similar fork a lot of separate processes, especially for some packages like libtorrent+rtorrent. Creating a new process is an expensive procedure in Windows compared to Unix-a-like OSs (which is part of the reason why threading is a far more popular concurrency model under Windows) so this is going to be slower under cygwin then Linux even without accounting for any OS call translation layer employed by the cygwin libraries.

Comment: @Shiki Cygwin has always been super slow. I avoid it like the plague, pretty much any open source tool I need under windows already has a native port (usually thanks to mingw32 / msys).

Comment: Ah thanks for the info,explanation. I'll try compiling stuff with ming32/msys then.Wanted to use mcabber for example which is a great tool.

Comment: accepting this, using rtorrent ;)

Comment: rtorrent won't compile for me under cygwin 64 (directory.cc:93:28: error: ‘struct dirent’ has no member named ‘d_reclen’)

Comment: It would appear that the version of rTorrent you are compiling relies on members of that type that are not required by the posix standards (but are presumably commonly present) and are nto implemented in Cygwin (or at least not in the version you have). It may be that the configure script is supposed to notice this and use a different code path (in which case that script just needs fixing) or it may be a change in Cygwin making it an incompatible platform. You should raise this with the rTorrent people (though it looks like some already have: http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-08/msg00127.html)

Answer (score 18):

[aria2](https://aria2.github.io/) is a command line downloader with BitTorrent support and Windows binaries available.

Answer (score 1):

I know Transmission has a command line client for its Unix releases that is called `transmission-cli`.

And I know they have a Windows client, but its newish.

It might have a command line interface. It's worth checking out

Comment: Transmission does have a CLI version (http://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/Building), but it needs to be compiled using Cygwin. (I wonder if it could be done using MingW/MSYS.)