# How to connect manually to seed of torrent data (OS: Windows 7, 64 bit)?

Tags: bittorrent

How to connect manually to seed of torrent data (OS: Windows 7, 64 bit)?

(I performed multiple web searches including on superuser.)

Answer (score 1):

Torrents occur as a [layer 7 application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent), rather than a simple network protocol. This means that to do it "manually" is to write your own client program, in the language of your choice.

The connections discovered, created, and managed by a torrent client are the result of complicated application logic, so its not a simple invocation like telnet'ing into a ftp server and running a GET, or using curl to operate a api. A full featured torrent client would use hundreds or thousands of these kinds of primitives to perform its tasks over the duration of a session.

if you would like to see how torrent clients work, there are many opensource implementations that you might look at:

- https://github.com/transmission/transmission
- https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent
- https://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/GitRepo

If you are just looking for a cli torrent client that you can script around or otherwise automate, I suggest you refine your search in those terms, and perhaps start here: [Torrent Client - Command line - Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/141158/torrent-client-command-line-windows)